# Creating polygons based on attributes in point layer using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-cluster, multipoint

I have a point layer of residential coordinates which includes an attribute field indicating the most visited hospital for the people living at the coordinate. From these data, I want to create a polygon layer of "hospital areas" that groups neighboring coordinates with the same most visited hospital, with a bit of an outside buffer, as illustrated below. Ideally, I want the polygons to cover also "weird" coordinate pairs, i.e. any coordinates which are clearly geographically located within a larger cluster with the same most visited hospital, but which they themselves have a deviating most visited hospital. Please see the example of Hospital B in the middle of the Hospital A cluster in my illustration.

How do I do this?

I don't have an advanced ArcMap license and have no python skills. The real data covers many thousand coordinate pairs and a total of 150 different hospitals.

[image: Desired grouping illustration]

Comment: Do you have spatial analyst extension?

Comment: Currently no. Would that solve the issue?

Comment: One of many possible solutions  using cost allocation.

Comment: I think I have vector solution. Perhaps save 5=6 noisy clusters somewhere to test.